# Bootstrap multiple modal confirm block parent modal

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

```
I am implement delete row confirmation modal.
```

I'm try used "data-backdrop="static"", but this operation not help.
    For example: "http://jsfiddle.net/KQXqM/"
    If open "FG modal" I can close "BG modal". How implement block parent modal("BG modal") when open child modal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you want to prevent the parent modal from closing while the child modal is open, you would so something like this..

```
$('#myModal2').on('show', function() {
    $('#myModal').css('opacity', .5);
    $('#myModal').unbind();
});
$('#myModal2').on('hidden', function() {
    $('#myModal').css('opacity', 1);
    $('#myModal').removeData("modal").modal({});
});
```

<kbd>[**Bootply Demo**](http://bootply.com/61322)</kbd>